# What info is exchanged when using Import[url]?

Tags: import, web-access

When using `Import` with a *url* what information is broadcasted/sent to the receiving end of the request and is it possible to monitor/modify that information?

Comment: It might be easier to do something like `ImportString[URLRead[url]]` and modify the parameters in `URLRead`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NetworkPacketRecording](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetworkPacketRecording.html) or [NetworkPacketCapture](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetworkPacketCapture.html) to record / capture network packet activity during `Import`.

You could also use a tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Can you elaborate on what you mean by "modify that information"?

Comment: I was hoping there was something similar like the properties in [`URLRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLRead.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is not documentation for this at this time, I suggest using `ImportString[URLRead[url]]` etc like Carl suggests.